# Foto de banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, microsoft-excel, excel-vba

Tenho uma planilha que preciso colocar fotos puxando de uma base de dados.

O gatilho seria o código do produto. Quando digitar o código do produto, a foto do mesmo subiria para a planilha automaticamente direto da base de dados, para uma célula específica com medidas.

Teria como fazer isso?

Comment: Olá, Samuel! Seja bem-vindo. Você pode nos dizer se já tentou ou pensou em algo? Se sim, edite sua pergunta explicando o que já tentou fazer.

Comment: Na verdade eu não tentei... Eu sei que tem como puxar fotos de banco de dados para uma planilha, porque já vi fazer.... mas não sei como montar.